# '> instead of -> in mysql command line client?

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

Im using mac os terminal to insert data into the table of mysql database. 
I accidentally pressed something and instead of -> now i see '>. I have no idea what it means, what is it and how can i get back to ->?
It doesn't react to any commands, just lets me type any text.
Ok i figured it out, can't delete the question though... Thank you for reading

Answer (score 1):

You have an opening single quote without a closing single quote.

Just type another single quote and either continue typing your query, ending with ; or just type ';

Example:

```
mysql> select * from table where name like '
    '>
    '>
    '> fred';
```